# application.cfc and page handling/propagation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, application.cfc

Is it possible to render a different page when the requested page does not exist using the OnRequestStart event handler?

```
function onRequestStart( string targetPage ) {
    // handle another page
} 

if(FileExists(cgi.script_name)){
    include cgi.script_name;
}else{
    // render another page
}
```

if I use the include directly instead of passing it through onRequestStart, I get an error about missing SESSION

If I don't abort the execution, I get the `File not found` error. Is there a way to skip trying to find the file and use the onRequestStart event to render a different page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to prevent a 404 of a coldFusion page (e.g. /index2.cfm) where the cfm template doesn't exists you can use `onMissingTemplate()` in your application.cfc

If the template that causes the 404 isn't something handled by CF (i.e .htm,.html) then you will have to catch it in the webserver using a custom 404 page or possibly a url rewite

Answer (score -1):

Try this insted

```
OnError()
```

> This fires if an exception gets thrown and is not caught by the controlling code.

Check this article
[Ben Nadel on application.cfc](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm)

Comment: OnError() handles ColdFusion errors.  A page not found is not a ColdFusion error so I don't think onError() will help.

Comment: OK, I agree with you. First thought was that i could do something to instantly solve the problem, but approach is not correct. 404 is not handled by onError